# How to disable keys on all of the page except for text boxes

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, key

On my website I have used the following code:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) 
    {
    return false;
    }
  </script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
   document.onkeyup = function (e) 
   {
   return false;
   }
 </script>
```

On my site header, however, I want users to just be able to type in a chat text box and nowhere else. The code for the chat text box is:

```
  <div style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-
  select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" unselectable="on"
   onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">

  <script type='text/javascript'>
  document.onkeydown = function (e) 
  {
  return true;
  }
  </script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
  document.onkeyup = function (e) 
  {
   return true;
  }
  </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" async> ;
 (function(o,l,a,r,k,y)
{if(o.olark)return; 
r="script";y=l.createElement(r);r=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0]; 
y.async=1;y.src="//"+a;r.parentNode.insertBefore(y,r); y=o.olark=function()
{k.s.push(arguments);k.t.push(+new Date)}; y.extend=function(i,j)
{y("extend",i,j)}; y.identify=function(i){y("identify",k.i=i)}; 
y.configure=function(i,j){y("configure",i,j);k.c[i]=j}; k=y._={s:[],t:[+new 
Date],c:{},l:a}; })(window,document,"static.olark.com/jsclient/loader.js");
/* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */
olark.identify('2624-366-10-5413');
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 document.onkeydown = function (e) {
     return false;

 }


 </script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   document.onkeyup = function (e) 
 {
   return false;
 }
 </script>
```

That was the full code that I've written so far.

Comment: What do you mean by *nowhere else*? Do you have other input fields on the page that you don't want them using? If so, why are they there at all? Can't you just disabled them if you can't remove them?

Comment: @BSMP i want them to be disabled everywhere but in the chat.

Comment: @javamaster yeah i don't understand what you mean either. Why are there other input fields on your page if their not to be used. Please don't say that your styling your page with inputs.

Comment: you can use e.target property it will give you the element on which you have pressed the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/7vv9hbw8/)**

JAVASCRIPT :-

```
    document.onkeyup = function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
  if(e.target.tagName == "INPUT"){
   console.log(e.target.type);
    if(e.target.type == "text"){
        alert("Can press the key");
        return true;
    }
  }
 alert("Can't press the key"); 
 return false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
 if(e.target.tagName == "INPUT"){
   console.log(e.target.type);
    if(e.target.type == "text"){
        alert("Can press the key");
        return true;
    }
  }
 alert("Can't press the key"); 
 return false;
}
```

HTML :-

```
    <input type="text" />
<textarea></textarea>
```